# Add PPOOE layer tp packet - convert length into byte

Tags: c#, .net, packet, libpcap

I have application that play `Pcap` files and i try to add function that wrap my packet with `PPPOE` layer.

so almost all done except large packets that i didn't understand yet how to set the new langth after add `PPPOE` layer.

For example this packet:

[image]

As you can see this packet length is `972 bytes (03 cc)`, and all i want is to convert it to decimal, after see this `packet byte[]` in my code i can see that this value converted into `3 and 204` in my packet `byte[]`, so my question is how this calculation works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two bytes represents a short ([System.Int16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) in bigendian notation (most significant byte first).

You can follow two approaches to get the decimal value of those two bytes. One is with the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, the other is by doing the calculation your self.

#### BitConverter

```
// the bytes
var bytes = new byte[] {3, 204};
// are the bytes little endian?
var littleEndian = false;  // no

// What architecure is the BitConverter running on?
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian != littleEndian) 
{
   // reverse the bytes if endianess mismatch
   bytes = bytes.Reverse().ToArray();
}
// convert
var value =  BitConverter.ToInt16( bytes , 0);
value.Dump(); // or Console.WriteLine(value); --> 972
```

#### Calculate your self

base 256 of two bytes:

```
// the bytes
var bytes2 = new byte[] {3, 204};
// [0] * 256 + [1]
var value2 = bytes2[0] * 256 + bytes2[1];  // 3 * 256 + 204
value2.Dump();  // 972
```